# How do I read a large .conll file with python?

Tags: python-3.x

My attempt to read a very large file with `pyconll` and `conllu` keeps running into memory errors. The file is **27Gb** in size and even using iterators to read it does not help. I'm using python 3.7.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the errors.

Comment: read this `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-large-text-files-in-python/`

Answer (score 0):

Both pyconll and conllu have iterative versions that use less memory at a given moment. If you call `pyconll.load_from_file` it is going to try to read and parse the entire file into memory and likely your machine has much less than 27Gb of RAM. Instead use `pyconll.iter_from_file`. This will read the sentences one by one and use minimal memory, and you can extract that's needed from those sentences piecemeal.

If you need to do some larger processing that requires having all information at once, it's a bit outside the scope of either of these libraries to support that type of scenario.